# What does ${python3:Depends} mean in a debian source-package control file?

Tags: python, debian, packaging, deb

I'm trying to build a .deb from a python package. In order to do so I have to configure a `control` file. The control file contains a line where you can define dependencies for your package, e.g:

```
Depends: python-appindicator, python3-yaml (>=3.11), ${misc:Depends}, ${python3:Depends}
```

The dependency definition for `python3-yaml` is easy to understand, but what do `${misc:Depends}` and `${python3:Depends}` stand for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that during build process variable `${python3:Depends}` will be replaced with guessed py3 dependencies for that package. `dh_python3` will help to do that. It's trying to guess what are the dependencies of package which contains such entry by looking for `requires.txt` file within the build directory, for example at `debian/python-foo/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/foo-0.0.1.egg-info/requires.txt` and then translating it to the debian-like dependencies. Also `${misc:Depends}` means such types of dependencies that are being involved by debhelper itself (by some of dh_* utilities).

Comment: My package requires a dependency called `PyYAML`. That is the name for it in `requirements.txt` and on `PyPi`. The Debian equivalent for this package is called `python3-yaml`. Do I have to specify `python3-yaml` in the `control` file or will it be included automatically if I have `PyYAML` in `requirements.txt`?

Comment: There is no need to specify that package explicitly, it will be translated from `requirements.txt` to debian-like dependency automatically and placed instead of `${python3:Depends}` if it's in there. For some exceptions there are dictionary files to help `dh-python` with translating at `/usr/share/dh-python/dist/`. But for good practice is recommended to set that dependencies explicitly.